# Why ControlValueAccessor doesn't update my value inside the component?

Tags: angular

Why when I use ControlValueAccessor the value doesn't update and reflect with reactive form?

In my application I have a form:

```
 profileForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(1),
  });
```

And I pass `name` from `profileForm` using `formControlName` into `my-comp` (ControlValueAccessor) component.

Now, when I click on the button: `changeValueFromMyApp` from the app component to change the name to 2 using patchValue is update the `profileForm` and the value inside the `my-comp` component. (because it invoke the writeValue method).

But when I click inside `my-comp` component on `changeValueFromMyComp` button to change the value to 4, the parent change ( `profileForm`) but the change doesn't reflect to `my-comp`. Why? What is missing here? how to make it work?

**app.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <form [formGroup]="profileForm">
      <my-comp formControlName="name"></my-comp>

    </form>

    form value: {{ profileForm.value | json }}
    <button (click)="changeValueFromMyApp()">changeValueFromMyApp</button>
  `

})
export class AppComponent  {
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(1),
  });


  changeValueFromMyApp() {
    this.profileForm.patchValue({
      name: 2
    });
  }
}
```

**my-comp.ts:**

```
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template:`
    value inside the component is: {{value | json}}

    <button (click)="changeValueFromMyComp()">change the value to 4</button>

  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyComp),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class MyComp implements ControlValueAccessor {

  value;
  onChange = () => {};
  onTouch = () => {};

  writeValue(value) {
    // this is happends when the parent change the value?
    this.value = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouch(fn) {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }

  changeValueFromMyComp() {
    this.onChange(4);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to update the variable 'value' here (my-comp.ts):

```
changeValueFromMyComp() {
    this.onChange(4);
    this.value = 4;
}
```

The onChange function doesnt update the value automatically.

Comment: weird. of course I can change the value locally. but I thought that it's two-way databinding. So this is the angular way? can you point me to reference on angular.io that refer to this issue?

Comment: @JonSud, Soukyone say you that you need change the "value" (the variable of MyComp) too. Yes are two steps:`this.value=4;this.onChange(this.value)`. writeValue give value to "value" when we change the value of formControl outside the component

Comment: I mean, you never update the value in your MyComp component, you only call onChange, and onChange doesnt update any variable, it simply notice parent component. There is not any binding with 'value', you can call it 'toto', it same.